# View *.eps files

Tags: 13.04, evince, eps

Since Evince doesn't work with `*.eps` on 13.04 (see bellow), is there any other app to **quickly** open (not edit) a `*.eps` file?

```
petr@sova:~$ evince histogram_default.eps 
undefined -21
undefined -21

(evince:12208): EvinceDocument-CRITICAL **: ev_document_misc_pixbuf_from_surface: assertion `surface' failed

(evince:12208): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `ghostscript` from the command line.  This has worked for me.  It may need to be installed from the repositories if not present on your system.  `sudo apt-get install ghostscript` or the equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I actually had it installed, so I just added a GUI around it as well: `gv`.

Comment: Ah, good.  Was trying to remember the name of 'gv' as I wrote that  -- did you already have 'gv' as an existing executable?

Comment: No, had `ghostscript` only. Had to install `gv`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, this is a bug of  Ghostscript.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1159931
http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693843

It has a problem dealing with the decimal separator "," in some locales. To workaround you can start evince like this:

```
LANG=en_US evince my_file.ps
```